# Can you construct pyspark.pandas.DataFrame from pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to Spark / Databricks. My question is whether is it recommended / possible to mix sql and Pandas API dataframes? Is it possible to create a [pyspark.pandas.DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/frame.html) directly from a [pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html), or I need to re-read the parquet file?

```py
# Suppose you have an SQL dataframe (now I read Boston Safety Data from Microsoft Open Dataset)
blob_account_name = "azureopendatastorage"
blob_container_name = "citydatacontainer"
blob_relative_path = "Safety/Release/city=Boston"
blob_sas_token = r""

wasbs_path = 'wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name, blob_relative_path)
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.blob.core.windows.net' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name), blob_sas_token)
print('Remote blob path: ' + wasbs_path)

df = spark.read.parquet(wasbs_path)

# Convert df to pyspark.pandas.Dataframe
df2 =   # ...?
```

Tried `df.toPandas()`, that is not good, because it converts to plain, undistributed `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

A workaround is to read the parquet again into a `pyspark.pandas.Dataframe` which I try to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you are looking to convert a spark dataframe to a pandas on spark dataframe.

You can do so with [`to_pandas_on_spark`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark.html) method.

```
df2 = df.to_pandas_on_spark()

print(type(df2))

<class 'pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: `to_pandas_on_spark()` is being deprecated, use `pandas_api()` instead [LINK](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.pandas_api.html)